# Links in Inbox / Achievements menu are not using current connection protocol

Tags: feature-request, ssl

When I browse SO using https - and I click on a link in the inbox / reputation menus, it loads the site using http.

Ideally all would force SSL - but shouldn't they at least use the current protocol?

Comment: I don't recall SSL being fully supported on Stack Exchange just yet.

Comment: @Makoto - I believe you are correct. But this is worth posting anyway. The site shouldnt strip it in some places but not others.